# Cohomology of exterior powers of Kähler Differentials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X=\mathbb{P}^n_k$ be the projective space over a field $k$ of dimension $n$ and denote by $\Omega$ the sheaf of differentials. I want to show that,
$$\operatorname{dim}_k H^i(X,\Lambda^j\Omega)\begin{cases}1 \text{ if } i=j\leq n\\ 0 \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I can easily derive the case $j=1$ with the help of Euler's exact sequence but for the case of $j>1$ if I apply $\Lambda^j$ to the Euler's exact sequence I get this description [Eisenbud's proof of right-exactness of the exterior algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551982/eisenbuds-proof-of-right-exactness-of-the-exterior-algebra) which is not very useful.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $F=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)^{n+1}$, then you have an exact sequence,
$$0\to \Omega^j\to\wedge^j F\to\Omega^{j-1}\to 0,$$ and then you should be able to calculate everything using induction on $j$.

Comment: by $\Omega^j$ do you mean $\Lambda^j\Omega$?

Comment: These are interchangeably used notations for the same thing.