# Non-zero element in exterior power

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ and consider $I=(2,\, 1+\sqrt{5})$ as an $R$-module. I'm struggling to prove that the element $2\wedge (1+\sqrt{5})$ of the exterior power $\Lambda^2(I)$ is non-zero. I should construct some alternating bilinear map from $I\times I$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ (regarded in some way as an $R$-module?) not sending $(2,\, 1+\sqrt{5})$ in $0$: I'm thinking of something similar to the determinant since each element $u\in I$ can be expressed as $2a+b(1+\sqrt{5})$, but it seems it doesn't work so well... Any idea about how to do this?

See also Remark 4.7 here: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf

Comment: What is your definition of $\wedge^2(I)$ here? Apparently some kind of a quotient of $I\otimes_SI$, but surely the answer then depends on whether $S=R$ or $S=\Bbb{Z}$. In the latter case $I$ is a rank two free module, and $\wedge^2I$ is a free module of rank one (and the answer to your question is obvious). If $S=R$ and $\wedge^2(I)$ is to be viewed as an $R$-module, then this likely to be torsion, but may still be non-zero.

Comment: I may be wrong, but the fact that you look for a bilinear map $I\times I\to\Bbb{Z}$ suggests to me that the tensor product might be over $\Bbb{Z}$ as well. That's why I ask.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $\Lambda^2(I)$ is the exterior power (see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf ) i.e. a quotient of $I\otimes I$ with the submodule generated by $a\otimes a$. I said in the question that I regarded $I$ as an $R$-module and that $\mathbb{Z}$ should be regarded as an $R$-module too. This is essentially Remark 4.7 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/extmod.pdf

Comment: Ok. But $\Bbb{Z}$ is not an $R$-module in any way. You need a bilinear map $I\times I\to ?$. And I'm thinking about the appropriate $?$

Comment: I would try and find a bilinear map from $I\times I\to R/P$, where $P$ is the ideal generated by $2$ and $1+\sqrt{5}$. After all, recycling the argument from Conrad's example 4.5. shows that $2\wedge(1+\sqrt5)$ is annihilated by all the elements of $P$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen If I define the map $\varphi: I\times I\rightarrow R/P$ to be the determinant map with respect to the $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $(2,\, 1+\sqrt{5})$ is seems that $(a'+b'\sqrt{5})(ad-bc)=a'ad-a'bc-ab'd+b'bc+P$ while $\varphi((a'+b'\sqrt{5})(2a+(1+\sqrt{5})b), 2c+(1+\sqrt{5})d))=a'ad-a'bc-ab'd-b'bc+P$, so they are not equal:, but they should be, yes?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Of course, if we factor by $2$, we have that $-b'bc+P=b'bc+P$! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have an exact sequence of $R$-modules
$$K\hookrightarrow R^2\xrightarrow{[2,1+\sqrt 5]}I\to\{0\}$$
where
$$K=\{(1+\sqrt 5)b-2d,(1+\sqrt 5)d-2(b+d)):b,d\in\Bbb Z\}\subseteq I^2$$
By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/552784), we get a commutative diagram of $R$-module homomorphisms with exact rows $\require{AMScd}$:
\begin{CD}
K\otimes_R\Lambda_R^1(R^2)@>>>\Lambda_R^2(R^2)@>>>\Lambda_R^2(I)@>>>\{0\}\\
@V\sim VV@V\sim VV@|\\
K\otimes_RR^2@>>\varphi>R@>>\psi>\Lambda_R^2(I)@>>>\{0\}
\end{CD}
where $\varphi((h,k)\otimes(u,v))=hv-ku$ and $\psi(1)=2\wedge(1+\sqrt 5)$.
If $\pi:R\to R/I$ denote the canonical projection, then $\pi\circ\varphi=0$, hence $\pi$ factors through $\psi$ giving rise to a non-zero $R$-module homomorphism $\Lambda_R^2(I)\to R/I$.